# Is it possible to play sound from one iOS device to another?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, p2p

I'd like to somehow play music from one iOS device simultaneously on another, sort of like AirPlay, but from device to device.

It seems that by leveraging existing BT tech I should be able to make this happen, but I just haven't seen any examples nor have I read anything that suggests it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following threads which might help to answer your question.

[iOS Stream Audio from one iOS Device to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357514/ios-stream-audio-from-one-ios-device-to-another)

[How do I stream AVAsset audio wirelessly form one iOS device to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687963/how-do-i-stream-avasset-audio-wirelessly-form-one-ios-device-to-another)

Comment: wow...unbelievable that that post didn't show up in my initial Google search or as I began to create the question.  Thanks AnkitJain.